# How can i execute text as code from server to client on shell script (netcat)

Tags: shell-script, netcat, dialog

I have two files, `client.sh` and `server.sh`, all the necessary data is on the server, which is sent to the client using **netcat**, the client just get these data and display it to the end user, the problem is when the server send some multiline code, the client just receive it as text and display on screen

### client.sh

```
ip=127.0.0.1
client_port=5678
server_port=8765

while :
do
        # Request the menu from the server
        echo menu > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$server_port"
        # Waits the server response
        nc -l $porta_cliente
done
```

### server.sh

```
ip=127.0.0.1
porta_cliente=5678
porta_servidor=8765

while :
do
        nc -vv -l $porta_servidor > logservidor
        echo "Texto recebido: "`cat logservidor` # LOG
        case `cat logservidor` in
        "splash")
                echo "dialog --stdout --msgbox 'SPLASH' 0 0" > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_c$
        ;;
        "menu_inicial")
                nc $ip $porta_cliente <<-EOF
                        dialog --stdout --backtitle 'Bem vindo ao SEPA 0.1' --title 'Me$
                        Cadastrar 'Criar um novo usuário' \
                        Entrar 'Fazer login com sua conta' \
                        Sair 'Encerrar o SEPA'

                        # Caso o usuário selecione Cancelar, a execução do script será $
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                                echo SUCESSO
                        else
                                rm resposta_servidor dados_digitados 2> /dev/null
                                clear
                                exit
                        fi
                EOF
        ;;
        "menu_principal")
                echo "dialog --msgbox 'MENU_PRINCIPAL' 0 0" > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_cl$
        ;;
        *)
                dialog --msgbox 'WTF?!' 0 0 > /dev/tcp/"$ip"/"$porta_cliente"
        ;;
        esac
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output of netcat into the shell

```
nc -l $porta_cliente | sh
```

however, on a socket with no authentication whatsoever, **be extremely careful as this could allow anyone to execute arbitrary code on the client machine**.

This method is extremely bad practice and you should consider different approaches.

Comment: Thank you, but do you know any safer alternative?

Comment: I used `nc -l $porta_cliente | sh` as you said, but when the server receive the text, the following line `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` is automatically setting the $? to 0, so i can´t verify if the user pressed cancel on dialog, any workaround?

Comment: You would need to replace `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` with `if [ \$? -eq 0 ]; then` since it's being substituted in there heredoc before it's sent over netcat.

Comment: As for alternatives, it really depends on what your program wants to be able to do and how much variation the code may have. Have a look at how [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is used for a better feel of what kind of information you should be sending over. Keep in mind that with internet, possibly anyone could be seeing the information and at the same time possibly anyone could change the information. In this environment, you should not be sending code over such a channel.

Comment: Thank you a lot! you don´t even have idea how you helped me :)

Comment: Just one more question: i´m trying to put the dialog inside a variable, like `main_menu=$(dialog --stdout --msgbox 'Example' 0 0)` but when i do this, the dialog is shown on the server when it should be displayed on the client, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect your text from the netcat connection to a file, and then execute it as a command, using `source`

Example:

```
nc -l 8765 > command
source command
```